# AngularJs routing issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I have some problem with angularjs routing. My goal is to append different view depending on the path. I want to implement this using different ng-apps in one html document like this:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="header" id='header'>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <div ng-app="content" id='content'>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the app.js:

```
angular.module('content', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    debugger;
  $routeProvider 
  .when('/101DEV/createProfile/', {templateUrl: '/101DEV/views/new-profile.html'})
  .otherwise({templateUrl: '/101DEV/views/page-not-found.html'})
}]);


angular.module('header', []).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.otherwise({templateUrl: '/101DEV/views/top-menu.html'})
}]);


angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('header'), ['header']);
angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById('content'), ['content']);
```

The header part is appended fine but the content part is not appended even the path is the same as I expect to get.. Can't find where the problem is.

Comment: what does debugger stands for?

Comment: it is just a breakpoint I put to check that the path is okay.

Comment: i don't think that is the problem because otherwise is placed in module that works fine. it means that this view is always appended not depending on the path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one ng-app in the HTML (See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngApp). Just get rid of the `ng-app`s in the HTML and do the manual bootstrapping you have at the bottom.

```
<body>
    <div id='header'>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <div id='content'>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SqK4d/